# Is there any Google Speech to Text API health check endpoint

Tags: google-api, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

Is there any endpoint that could be called to check if google speech to text api is working?

I need to check in time intervals if
us-speech.googleapis.com and eu-speech.googleapis.com
are not down

Comment: Have you consider pinging the server?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.